# Getting JSON from a .NET web service with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am working with the FullCalendar module (great, btw) and I'm having trouble populating events from the database. I am receiving a JSON string created by a C# web service. However, when I try to parse it and print out test alerts, I get nothing but "undefined".

My response string looks like this in Firebug:

```
{d="[{"ScheduleRecId":9,"EmployeeScheduled":"3","TimeStart":"\/Date(1285601677000)\/","TimeEnd":"\/Date(1285601677000)\/","UpdatedBy":"4","LastUpdate":"\/Date(1285601677000)\/","Started":true,"Finished":false}]"}
```

which appears to be an array, but when I try to access it from JQuery like:

```
 success: function(doc) {
              alert(doc)    //echos "Object oject"
              alert(doc[0]) //echos "undefined"
              alert(doc.EmployeeScheduled) //echos "null"
 }
```

I also tried using JSON.parse and eval() with not much luck. How can I access the properties of this object?

**UpDate:**
After Nick's answer, I decided to try `alert(doc.d[0]);` which echoed `[`

I noticed that if I tried `alert(doc.d[5]);` I get `h` leading me to believe doc.d is coming across as a character array. I suppose I could read it in and parse it, but shouldn't there be a cleaner way to access the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was this:

```
 success: function(obj) {

      var schedules = (eval(obj.d));
```

then I could capture the properties like this:

```
var event = {
                id: schedules[0].ScheduleRecId,
            }
```

Comment: I usually change my code written with .net 2 as following
success: function(obj) {
var doc = obj.d;
then you can use your doc as usual

Comment: Thanks, that's a little easier to understand and maintain. I will make that change.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's from ASP.NET 3.5 or higher it looks like, you need the `d` property, like this:

```
success: function(doc) {
    alert(doc.d[0].EmployeeScheduled);
}
```

This is because the root object has one property, `d`, which is an array of objects...so use `[0]` to get the first entry, then `.EmployeeScheduled` to get that property.

Comment: I got "undefined" with this. I double checked and found in a different place in Firebug showing the entire string enclosed in {} (I updated my post) - would this change what the alert should look like?

Comment: @cinqoTimo -Are you looking at the JSON tab or the Net tab to see the raw response?